# Which R implementation gives the fastest JSD matrix computation?

Tags: r, performance, algorithm, matrix, apply

JSD matrix is a similarity matrix of distributions based on [Jensen-Shannon divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence).
Given matrix m which rows present distributions we would like to find JSD distance between each distribution. Resulting JSD matrix is a square matrix with dimensions nrow(m) x nrow(m). This is triangular matrix where each element contains JSD value between two rows in m.

JSD can be calculated by the following R function:

```
JSD<- function(x,y) sqrt(0.5 * (sum(x*log(x/((x+y)/2))) + sum(y*log(y/((x+y)/2)))))
```

where x, y are rows in matrix m.

I experimented with different JSD matrix calculation algorithms in R to figure out the quickest one. For my surprise, the algorithm with two nested loops performs faster than the different vectorized versions (parallelized or not). I'm not happy with the results. Could you pinpoint me better solutions than the ones I game up?

```
library(parallel)
library(plyr)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

nodes <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

m <- runif(24000, min = 0, max = 1)
m <- matrix(m, 24, 1000)
prob_dist <- function(x) t(apply(x, 1, prop.table))
JSD<- function(x,y) sqrt(0.5 * (sum(x*log(x/((x+y)/2))) + sum(y*log(y/((x+y)/2)))))
m <- t(prob_dist(m))
m[m==0] <- 0.000001
```

Algorithm with two nested loops:

```
dist.JSD_2 <- function(inMatrix) {
  matrixColSize <- ncol(inMatrix)
  resultsMatrix <- matrix(0, matrixColSize, matrixColSize)
  for(i in 2:matrixColSize) {
    for(j in 1:(i-1)) { 
      resultsMatrix[i,j]=JSD(inMatrix[,i], inMatrix[,j])
    }
  }
  return(resultsMatrix) 
}
```

Algorithm with outer:

```
dist.JSD_3 <- function(inMatrix) {
  matrixColSize <- ncol(inMatrix)
  resultsMatrix <- outer(1:matrixColSize,1:matrixColSize, FUN = Vectorize( function(i,j) JSD(inMatrix[,i], inMatrix[,j])))   
  return(resultsMatrix)
}
```

Algorithm with combn and apply:

```
dist.JSD_4 <- function(inMatrix) {
  matrixColSize <- ncol(inMatrix)
  ind <- combn(matrixColSize, 2)
  out <- apply(ind, 2, function(x) JSD(inMatrix[,x[1]], inMatrix[,x[2]]))
  a <- rbind(ind, out)
  resultsMatrix <- sparseMatrix(a[1,], a[2,], x=a[3,], dims=c(matrixColSize, matrixColSize))
  return(resultsMatrix)
}
```

Algorithm with combn and aaply:

```
dist.JSD_5 <- function(inMatrix) {
  matrixColSize <- ncol(inMatrix)
  ind <- combn(matrixColSize, 2)
  out <- aaply(ind, 2, function(x) JSD(inMatrix[,x[1]], inMatrix[,x[2]]))
  a <- rbind(ind, out)
  resultsMatrix <- sparseMatrix(a[1,], a[2,], x=a[3,], dims=c(matrixColSize, matrixColSize))
  return(resultsMatrix)
}
```

performance test:

```
mbm = microbenchmark(
  two_loops = dist.JSD_2(m),
  outer = dist.JSD_3(m),
  combn_apply = dist.JSD_4(m),
  combn_aaply = dist.JSD_5(m),
  times = 10
)
ggplot2::autoplot(mbm)
```

[image: benchmark plot]

```
> summary(mbm)
         expr      min       lq     mean   median
1   two_loops 18.30857 18.68309 23.50231 18.77303
2       outer 38.93112 40.98369 42.44783 42.16858
3 combn_apply 20.45740 20.90747 21.49122 21.35042
4 combn_aaply 55.61176 56.77545 59.37358 58.93953
        uq      max neval cld
1 18.87891 65.34197    10 a  
2 42.85978 48.82437    10  b 
3 22.06277 22.98803    10 a  
4 62.26417 64.77407    10   c
```

Comment: You should probably try to vectorize the JSD implementation itself.

Comment: I don't have any good idea how to do that. Could you give some hints?

Comment: Is not implemented in `entropy`?

Comment: As far as I understand, it is not in `entropy`.

Comment: do we need to use only count data or we can used any transformed data into for example normalised gene expression ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my implementation of your `dist.JSD_2`

```
dist0 <- function(m) {
    ncol <- ncol(m)
    result <- matrix(0, ncol, ncol)
    for (i in 2:ncol) {
        for (j in 1:(i-1)) {
            x <- m[,i]; y <- m[,j]
            result[i, j] <-
                sqrt(0.5 * (sum(x * log(x / ((x + y) / 2))) +
                            sum(y * log(y / ((x + y) / 2)))))
        }
    }
    result
}
```

The usual steps are to replace iterative calculations with vectorized versions. I moved `sqrt(0.5 * ...)` from inside the loops, where it is applied to each element of `result`, to outside the loop, where it is applied to the vector `result`.

I realized that `sum(x * log(x / (x + y) / 2))` could be written as `sum(x * log(2 * x)) - sum(x * log(x + y))`. The first sum is calculated once for each entry, but could be calculated once for each column. It too comes out of the loops, with the vector of values (one element for each column) calculated as `colSums(m * log(2 * m))`.

The remaining term inside the inner loop is `sum((x + y) * log(x + y))`. For a given value of `i`, we can trade off space for speed by vectorizing this across all relevant `y` columns as a matrix operation

```
j <- seq_len(i - 1L)
xy <- m[, i] + m[, j, drop=FALSE]
xylogxy[i, j] <- colSums(xy * log(xy))
```

The end result is

```
dist4 <- function(m) {
    ncol <- ncol(m)

    xlogx <- matrix(colSums(m * log(2 * m)), ncol, ncol)
    xlogx2 <- xlogx + t(xlogx)
    xlogx2[upper.tri(xlogx2, diag=TRUE)] <- 0

    xylogxy <- matrix(0, ncol, ncol)
    for (i in seq_len(ncol)[-1]) {
        j <- seq_len(i - 1L)
        xy <- m[, i] + m[, j, drop=FALSE]
        xylogxy[i, j] <- colSums(xy * log(xy))
    }

    sqrt(0.5 * (xlogx2 - xylogxy))
}
```

Which produces results that are numerically equal (though not exactly identical) to the original

```
> all.equal(dist0(m), dist4(m))
[1] TRUE
```

and about 2.25x faster

```
> microbenchmark(dist0(m), dist4(m), dist.JSD_cpp2(m), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
             expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
         dist0(m) 48.41173 48.42569 49.26072 48.68485 49.48116 51.64566    10
         dist4(m) 20.80612 20.90934 21.34555 21.09163 21.96782 22.32984    10
 dist.JSD_cpp2(m) 28.95351 29.11406 29.43474 29.23469 29.78149 30.37043    10
```

You'll still be waiting for about 10 hours, though that seems to imply a very large problem. The algorithm seems like it is quadratic in the number of columns, but the number of columns here was small (24) compared to the number of rows, so I wonder what the actual size of data being processed is? There are ncol * (ncol - 1) / 2 distances to be calculated.

A crude approach to further performance gain is parallel evaluation, which the following implements using `parallel::mclapply()`

```
dist4p <- function(m, ..., mc.cores=detectCores()) {
    ncol <- ncol(m)

    xlogx <- matrix(colSums(m * log(2 * m)), ncol, ncol)
    xlogx2 <- xlogx + t(xlogx)
    xlogx2[upper.tri(xlogx2, diag=TRUE)] <- 0

    xx <- mclapply(seq_len(ncol)[-1], function(i, m) {
        j <- seq_len(i - 1L)
        xy <- m[, i] + m[, j, drop=FALSE]
        colSums(xy * log(xy))
    }, m, ..., mc.cores=mc.cores)

    xylogxy <- matrix(0, ncol, ncol)
    xylogxy[upper.tri(xylogxy, diag=FALSE)] <- unlist(xx)

    sqrt(0.5 * (xlogx2 - t(xylogxy)))
}
```

My laptop has 8 nominal cores, and for 1000 columns I have

```
> system.time(xx <- dist4p(m1000))
   user  system elapsed 
 48.909   1.939   8.043
```

suggests that I get 48s of processor time in 8s of clock time. The algorithm is still quadratic, so this might reduce overall computation time to about 1h for the full problem. Memory might become an issue on a multicore machine, where all processes are competing for the same memory pool; it might be necessary to choose `mc.cores` less than the number available.

With large ncol, the way to get better performance is to avoid calculating the complete set of distances. Depending on the nature of the data it might make sense to filter for duplicate columns, or to filter for informative columns (e.g., with greatest variance), or... An appropriate strategy requires more information on what the columns represent and what the goal is for the distance matrix. The question 'how similar is company i to other companies?' can be answered without calculating the full distance matrix, just a single row, so if the number of times the question is asked relative to the total number of companies is small, then maybe there is no need to calculate the full distance matrix? Another strategy might be to reduce the number of companies to be clustered by (1) simplify the 1000 rows of measurement using principal components analysis, (2) kmeans clustering of all 50k companies to identify say 1000 centroids, and (3) using the interpolated measurements and Jensen-Shannon distance between these for clustering.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your contribution!
The actual number of columns is  50 000+  and the number of rows is about 1000.

Comment: @AndresKull I added some fairly lame ideas about how you might make further progress, but probably more information about your data and research question would be needed.

Comment: This blog post gives a very brief overview, where the JSD matrix fits in http://blog.funderbeam.com/5-competitive-startup-clustering-skills/

Comment: what do you mean by "using the interpolated measurements and Jensen-Shannon distance between these for clustering"?

Comment: @AndresKull I think the question has diverged from the original, and it would be worth-while to ask / investigate another question about 'clustering big data in R' or similar (I think there are posts on StackOverflow about this already...). It's not exactly a programming question either, so perhaps StackOverflow is not appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure there are better approaches than the following, but your `JSD` function itself can trivially be converted to an Rcpp function by just swapping `sum` and `log` for their Rcpp sugar equivalents, and using `std::sqrt` in place of the R's `base::sqrt`.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double cppJSD(const Rcpp::NumericVector& x, const Rcpp::NumericVector& y) {
  return std::sqrt(0.5 * (Rcpp::sum(x * Rcpp::log(x/((x+y)/2))) +
                          Rcpp::sum(y * Rcpp::log(y/((x+y)/2)))));
}
```

---

I only tested with your `dist.JST_2` approach (since it was the fastest version), but you should see an improvement when using `cppJSD` instead of `JSD` regardless of the implementation:

```
R> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    two_loops = dist.JSD_2(m),
    cpp = dist.JSD_cpp(m),
    times=100L)
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 two_loops 41.25142 41.34755 42.75926 41.45956 43.67520 49.54250   100
       cpp 36.41571 36.52887 37.49132 36.60846 36.98887 50.91866   100
```

---

**EDIT:** 
Actually, your `dist.JSD_2` function itself can easily be converted to an Rcpp function for an additional speed-up:

```
// [[Rcpp::export("dist.JSD_cpp2")]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix foo(const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& inMatrix) {
  size_t cols = inMatrix.ncol();
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix result(cols, cols);
  for (size_t i = 1; i < cols; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      result(i,j) = cppJSD(inMatrix(Rcpp::_, i), inMatrix(Rcpp::_, j));
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

(where `cppJSD` was defined in the same `.cpp` file as the above). Here are the timings:

```
R> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    two_loops = dist.JSD_2(m),
    partial_cpp = dist.JSD_cpp(m),
    full_cpp = dist.JSD_cpp2(m),
    times=100L)
Unit: milliseconds
        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   two_loops 41.25879 41.36729 42.95183 41.84999 44.08793 54.54610   100
 partial_cpp 36.45802 36.62463 37.69742 36.99679 37.96572 44.26446   100
    full_cpp 32.00263 32.12584 32.82785 32.20261 32.63554 38.88611   100
```

---

```
dist.JSD_2 <- function(inMatrix) {
  matrixColSize <- ncol(inMatrix)
  resultsMatrix <- matrix(0, matrixColSize, matrixColSize)
  for(i in 2:matrixColSize) {
    for(j in 1:(i-1)) { 
      resultsMatrix[i,j]=JSD(inMatrix[,i], inMatrix[,j])
    }
  }
  return(resultsMatrix) 
}
##
dist.JSD_cpp <- function(inMatrix) {
  matrixColSize <- ncol(inMatrix)
  resultsMatrix <- matrix(0, matrixColSize, matrixColSize)
  for(i in 2:matrixColSize) {
    for(j in 1:(i-1)) { 
      resultsMatrix[i,j]=cppJSD(inMatrix[,i], inMatrix[,j])
    }
  }
  return(resultsMatrix) 
}
```

---

```
m <- runif(24000, min = 0, max = 1)
m <- matrix(m, 24, 1000)
prob_dist <- function(x) t(apply(x, 1, prop.table))
JSD <- function(x,y) sqrt(0.5 * (sum(x*log(x/((x+y)/2))) + sum(y*log(y/((x+y)/2)))))
m <- t(prob_dist(m))
m[m==0] <- 0.000001
```

Comment: I see that in your summary the improvement from my best version to cpp_full is about 25%. I got significantly bigger improvement in my computer (about 50%).

Comment: Right, my laptop's processor only has two cores so the timings were quite a bit slower all around compared your original benchmarks. I'm glad it worked out for you though.

Comment: Yes, 50% improvement is definitely a good improvement. But this reduces my overall calculation time from 20 hours to 10 hours only :) Therefore, I'm looking forward if someone can help to vectorize the JSD function itself.